# Mark success all the planned but not scheduled

Tags: airflow

I have a dag (that I can't re-deploy) that has 100 days of planned runs that I would like to mark as success. I can't use "mark success" -> "future" as those runs are not scheduled before the previous run isn't mark success. Is there a way to speed up the process or do I need to mark success one by one and wait for the next run to be scheduled?

Comment: What do you mean by "planned runs"? What is the DAG's schedule?

Comment: Daily schedule. Let's say start_date for DAG is 2023-05-05, I want unpause it today but I don't want to run all the runs between the start_date and now. Also I can't redeploy the dag.

Answer (score 1):

Based on this comment:

> I want unpause it today but I don't want to run all the runs between the start_date and now. Also I can't redeploy the dag.

The solution is to set `catchup=False` in the DAG definition.

Reference: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/dag-run.html#catchup

Comment: Technically yes, but this is a specific situation where I can't redefine the DAG.

Comment: Hmm... why not?

Comment: internal policy.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the [backfill](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#backfill) command is a solution. it's just very slow.
`airflow dags backfill -m -s 2023-05-05 -e 2023-08-07 dag_name`